# Display the Group Amount of a product in SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a SQL Table with 3 Columns named Product, Type, Cost.

```
Product Type Cost
A        a    10
B        b    10
C        a     5
D        b     7
```

I have to add a new column called Groups Cost such that

```
Product Type Cost GroupsCost
A        a   10    15
B        b   10    17
C        a    5    15
D        b    7    17
```

It is displaying the total Cost of each Product of same type in every column of that type.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `SUM` here as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT Product, Type, Cost, SUM(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY Type) AS GroupsCost
FROM yourTable;
```